# powershell -split('') specify a new line

Tags: powershell, scripting, newline, line-breaks

```
Get-Content $user| Foreach-Object{
   $user = $_.Split('=')
   New-Variable -Name $user[0] -Value $user[1]}
```

Im trying to work on a script and have it split a text file into an array, splitting the file based on each new line

What should I change the "=" sign to

Comment: Note that `Get-Content $user` streams the content of file `$user` _line by line_ to the pipeline, which means that each line seen inside the `ForEach-Object` via the automatic `$_` variable by definition contains _no_ newlines anymore.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It depends on the exact encoding of the textfile, but `[Environment]::NewLine` usually does the trick.

```
"This is `r`na string.".Split([Environment]::NewLine)
```

Output:

> This is
>
> a string.

Comment: This will contain empty elements between each line in the original string.

Comment: Thank you * 1000! This helped me with dealing with the Message property within Windows Event logs, in particular Sysmon event logs.

Comment: Struggled across trying out loads of code snippets, but this small pearl worked like a charm! Thank you, @Ryan

Comment: To avoid the behavior described by @sinned, we can add use the following Split overload : .Split([Environment]::NewLine, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: @P-L Thank you for adding this! I had this same issue several years ago and was looking to remove the empty entries. Last time it took me about an hour to find what you posted. Thanks to your comment this time, it was a breeze.

Comment: To elaborate on @sinned's comment: The solution is broken with CRLF (``"`r`n"``) newlines in _Windows PowerShell_, because it treats CR and LF _individually_ as separators, and therefore creates an additional, empty array element for each CRLF sequence encountered. The solution would actually work in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, because the `.Split()` method now has an overload for a single _string_ as the  separator. Fundamentally, however, the solution wouldn't work for Unix-format LF newlines (``"`n"`` only) - which you can easily encounter on Windows too.

Comment: @P-L, note that removing _all_ empty elements may be undesired. A better solution is to avoid the spurious empty elements to begin with, namely with ``-split "`r`n"`` - or better yet, so as to match Unix-format LF-only newlines too, `-split '\r?\n'`. If you then want to eliminate (true) empty elements too, append `-ne ''`

Answer (score 31):

The problem with the `String.Split` method is that it splits on *each* character in the given string. Hence, if the text file has CRLF line separators, you will get empty elements.

Better solution, using the [`-Split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6).

```
"This is `r`na string." -Split "`r`n" #[Environment]::NewLine, if you prefer
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `String.Split` method to split on `CRLF` and not end up with the empty elements by using the [Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) method overload.

There are a couple different ways you can use this method to do it.

### Option 1

```
$input.Split([string[]]"`r`n", [StringSplitOptions]::None)
```

This will split on the combined `CRLF` (Carriage Return and Line Feed) string represented by `` `r`n ``. The `[StringSplitOptions]::None` option will allow the `Split` method to return empty elements in the array, but there should not be any if all the lines end with a `CRLF`.

### Option 2

```
$input.Split([Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This will split on ***either*** a Carriage Return or a Line Feed. So the array will end up with empty elements interspersed with the actual strings. The `[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries` option instructs the `Split` method to not include empty elements.

Comment: [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries #FTW

Answer (score 6):

The answers given so far consider only Windows as the running environment. If your script needs to run in a variety of environments (Linux, Mac and Windows), consider using the following snippet:

```
$lines = $string.Split(
    @("`r`n", "`r", "`n"), 
   [StringSplitOptions]::None)
```

Comment: Nice. Note that your solution needs tweaking in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): to find the right `.Split()` method overload there (as well), place `[string[]]` before ``@("`r`n", "`r", "`n")`` A more concise (though probably slower) alternative is to use `$string -split '\r?\n'`

Answer (score 3):

> have it split a text file into an array

Note that **[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)** does this *by default*, i.e. it **streams a text file's lines *one by one*** (with any trailing newline removed).

If you ***capture* this stream of lines as an *array***:

- If there are *two or more* lines, PowerShell *automatically* creates an array (of type `[object[]]`) for you.
- If there's only *one* line, PowerShell captures it as-is, as a `[string]`; to ensure that even a file with a single line is captured as an *array*, enclose the `Get-Content` call in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)

Therefore, the following captures the individual lines of file `$file` in an array (but see the faster alternative below):

```bash
# See faster alternative below.
$lines = @(Get-Content $file)
```

However, if the intent is to capture `Get-Content`'s output *in full*, it isn't actually necessary to  *stream* the lines by one; the `-ReadCount` parameter allows reading the file in *batches* of lines, as *arrays of the specified size*; `-ReadCount 0` reads *all* lines into an array, and *unconditionally* creates an array, i.e. also if there's only *one* line. Therefore, the following is a **much faster alternative**.

```bash
# Faster alternative to the above.
$lines = Get-Content -ReadCount 0 $file
```

Note that if the multiline input string also has a *trailing* newline (as you're likely to get if you use `Get-Content -Raw` to read a )

---

If your intent is to **split a *multiline* string into an array of individual lines**, use PowerShell's **[`-split`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)**:

- Its [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) capabilities make it easy to to match newlines (line breaks) in a *cross-platform* manner:  **regex `\r?\n` matches both Windows-format CRLF newlines (`\r\n`) and Unix-format LF newlines (`\n`)**

The following example uses a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to split a multiline string into lines, and visualizes each resulting line by enclosing it in `[...]`:

```bash
@'
line 1
line 2
line 3
'@ -split '\r?\n' |
   ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } # -> '[line 1]', '[line 2]', '[line 3]'
```

If you want to **avoid an empty final array element resulting from a *trailing newline*** (as you might get if you read a text file as a whole into a string, e.g. with `Get-Content -Raw`), apply regex `\r?\n\z` via the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) first:

```bash
# Multiline string with trailing newline.
@'
line 1
line 2
line 3

'@ -replace '\r?\n\z' -split '\r?\n' |
   ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } # -> '[line 1]', '[line 2]', '[line 3]'
```

If you want to **filter out *empty* lines**, use the filtering capabilities of PowerShell's comparison operators such as [`-ne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-ne), which return the *sub-array of matching elements* with an *array* as the LHS:

```bash
# Multiline string with empty lines.
@'
line 1

line 2
line 3

'@ -split '\r?\n' -ne '' |
   ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } # -> '[line 1]', '[line 2]', '[line 3]'
```

If you want to **filter out *empty or blank* (all-whitespace) lines**, you can use the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) (which equally has filtering capabilities) with regex `\S`, which matches any non-whitespace character and therefore only lines that are neither empty nor composed exclusively of whitespace chars.:

```bash
# The 2nd line is nonempty, but composed of spaces only
@'
line 1
    
line 2
line 3

'@ -split '\r?\n' -match '\S' |
   ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } # -> '[line 1]', '[line 2]', '[line 3]'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and unusual way to do this.

```
$lines = [string[]]$string
```

This will split `$string` like:

```
$string.Split(@("`r`n", "`n"))
```

This is undocumented at least in [docs for Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06?view=powershell-7.2#69-conversion-to-array).
Beware, this will not remove empty entries.
And it doesn't work for Carriage Return (`\r`) line ending at least on Windows.
Experimented in Powershell 7.2.

Comment: A `[string[]]` cast does _not_ perform any splitting - e.g. ``([string[]] "line 1`nline 2").Count`` yields `1`. As an aside: your `.Split()` method call wouldn't work as shown.

Answer (score -1):

This article also explains a lot about how it works with carriage return and line ends. https://virot.eu/powershell-and-newlines/

having some issues with additional empty lines and such i found the solution to understanding the issue. Excerpt from virot.eu:

> So what makes up a new line. Here comes the tricky part, it depends.
> To understand this we need to go to the line feed the character.
>
> Line feed is the ASCII character 10. It in most programming languages
> escaped by writing \n, but in powershell it is `n. But Windows is not
> content with just one character, Windows also uses carriage return
> which is ASCII character 13. Escaped \r. So what is the difference?
> Line feed advances the pointer down one row and carriage return
> returns it to the left side again. If you store a file in Windows by
> default are linebreaks are stored as first a carriage return and then
> a line feed (\r\n). When we aren’t using any parameters for the
> split() command it will split on all white-space characters, that is
> both carriage return, linefeed, tabs and a few more. This is why we
> are getting 5 results when there is both carriage return and line
> feeds.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)